# How to remove all pictures below a certain height using ImageMagick

Tags: cmd, imagemagick

i want to create a bat to delete files under a certain size to delete JPG AND PNG files under a certain height.

I already know how to return the height using ImageMagick. How do I combine a for loop and this code (convert image -ping -format "%h" info:) to delete files under a certain height?

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "min.height=1000"

for /f  "usebackq delims=;" %%A in (`dir /b /A:-D *.*`) do If convert %%A -ping -format "%h" info: LSS %min.height% del "%%A"
```

When I use that code, it tells me that %A was unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have/use `convert`, so I have to guess. If the command `convert "%%A" -ping -format "%%h" info:` just returns the height itself without additional text, the following will do (if there is more output, the `for /f` needs to be adapted). Also no need for `dir`, as a plain `for` loop is able to get the matching files itself.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "min.height=1000"
for %%A in (*.jpg *.png) do (
  for /f %%B in ('convert "%%A" -ping -format "%%h" info:') do (
    set /a "height=%%B"
    if !height! lss %min.height% (
      echo deleting %%A, because %%B is less than %min.height%
      ECHO del "%%A"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Had to remove the second "ECHO" but this is perfect, what a pro! thanks

Comment: We tend to "disarm" potential harmful commands (like `del`) by just echoing them. (Should have mentioned that `:)`). It's great for testing and troubleshooting.